# Gradient Descent converging faster for one parameter than the other parameter

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, linear-regression

I implemented my first (univariate) linear regression with gradient descent in JavaScript.

```
const LEARNING_RATE = 0.000001;

let m = 0;
let b = 0;

const hypothesis = x => m * x + b;

const learn = (alpha) => {
  if (x.length <= 0) return;

  let sum1 = 0;
  let sum2 = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    sum1 += hypothesis(x[i]) - y[i];
    sum2 += (hypothesis(x[i]) - y[i]) * x[i];
  }

  b = b - alpha * sum1 / (x.length);
  m = m - alpha * sum2 / (x.length);
}

// repeat until convergence learn(LEARNING_RATE);
```

The slope for m in the hypothesis adjusts quickly, but the intersection at the y-axis takes ages to adjust. I had to use a different learning rate for b to make it work.

```
const learn = (alpha) => {
  if (x.length <= 0) return;

  let sum1 = 0;
  let sum2 = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    sum1 += hypothesis(x[i]) - y[i];
    sum2 += (hypothesis(x[i]) - y[i]) * x[i];
  }

  b = b - 100000 * alpha * sum1 / (x.length);
  m = m - alpha * sum2 / (x.length);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what is wrong with the algorithm? It can be found in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rwieruch/linear-regression-gradient-descent/blob/master/src/App.js) and in [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/linear-regression-gradient-descent-javascript/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to look at speed of convergence to global minimum not at speed of changes of bias. There are no error in model (Maybe you just forget 2/N coefficient but for m and b coefficient this parameter will be 1.).

As you know gradient descent method is using error from prediction for updating weights on each iteration. So if your bias get small error then updates will grab small changes. It's normal behavior for model.

[There are](https://machinelearningmastery.com/linear-regression-tutorial-using-gradient-descent-for-machine-learning/) example with good explanation.

PS. Custom change for learning rate can lead you to anomaly behavior and problem with reducing to gminimum. Recommend [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/QKEdR/gradient-descent-intuition).
[image: link for course I have posted above]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did I get you right, that there is no mistake in the algorithm itself? But it just takes time to learn with a small learning rate?

Comment: Yes, i didn't find any mistakes. Yes, for small learning rate you'll find gminimal later.